# Sequence contains no elements on query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**Query:**

```
var result = await this.Context.ShopProducts
    .Include(prd => prd.Category)
        .ThenInclude(cat => cat.Culture)
    .Include(prd => prd.InfoItems)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(prd => prd.Id.Equals(id) && prd.CategoryId.Equals(culture));
```

> Edit: Updated the entities and query to reflect the new design and added a sql query

Entities:

**Product:**

```
[Table("ShopProduct")]
public class Product : ShopBase
{
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductInfo> InfoItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<ProductInfo>();
}
```

**ProductInfo:**

```
[Table("ShopProductInfo")]
public class ProductInfo : ShopBase
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CultureId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Sum { get; set; }        

    public ICollection<GraphicItem> GraphicItems { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to only select the ProductInfo objects with CultureId that equals the Category CultureId property. When selecting I provide the product Id and Category Id.

I want to replicate something like this sql query:

```
DECLARE @prdId  INT,
        @catId  INT

SET @prdId = 1
SET @catId = 1

SELECT  prd.*, 
        info.*, 
        cat.* 
FROM    ShopProduct prd, 
        ShopProductInfo info, 
        ShopCategory cat 
WHERE   prd.Id = @prdId
AND     prd.CategoryId = cat.Id
AND     cat.Id = @catId
AND     cat.CultureId = info.CultureId
```

Comment: What do your entities look like?

Comment: I think you can separate query to check data. For example:  var lstData = await this.Context.ShopProducts
    .Include(prd => prd.Category)
        .ThenInclude(cat => cat.Culture)
    .Include(prd => prd.Prices) and then check continue...

Comment: It's not about `CultureId`. `SingleAsync(prd => prd.Id.Equals(id))` doesn't give a match.

Comment: @GertArnold the query works without **.Where(prc => prc.CultureId.Equals(culture))** so I know it should find a product with the supplied Id.. Is the actual query syntax I use correct?

Comment: What is `ShopProducts` by the way? Note that the Where applies to `this.Context.ShopProducts`. It's a bit confusing that `CultureId` is all over the place. Easy to make errors.

Comment: ShopProducts is the DbSet for the table named ShopProducts. Culture is there to support different cultures in all Shop tables. I just need to figure this one out so I can implement it on all queries on tables in the Shop service. The database will contain tables for different services, Shop is one of them.

Comment: It *looks* like a crosscutting concern implemented the wrong way. But tha't not the topic. Did you understand this part: "Note that the Where applies to `this.Context.ShopProducts`"? It's not a filter on prices! Includes can't be filtered.

Comment: Ok... Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @TheRuler where is the entity for ShopProducts, what does that look like?

Comment: @TheRuler - Asking for clarification on the query. What is the returned object you are expecting? You state you want to select prices but your query is selecting Product. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Also the error is because of `SingleAsync` the where clause is being applied to `Product.CultureId`

Comment: I've changed the design a bit, but the problem is still there. How to only select ProductInfo objects with the correct CultureId.

Answer (score -1):

this error mean, linq query return some value otherwise give exception error

Comment: OP didn't ask what the error means but why it occurs.